# How to call JS function continuously after every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have following codes:

JSP code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/nextprevpage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body onload="javascript:first();">

<div id="getData">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code present in nextprevpage.js is as follows:

```
function first()
{

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{   // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
    {
        document.getElementById("getData").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
  // here you make a request to your script to check your database...
xmlhttp.open("POST", "updatesession.jsp?", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Now I have another jsp page as updatesession.jsp.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body ">
 Hello......
</body>
</html>
```

I called above js function using onload() event. I need to call this js function continuously. Is there any way to call this function every after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Syntax: `window.setInterval(func, delay);`

```
 function first(){

  ....
   xmlhttp.send();
  window.setInterval(first, 10000);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `window.setInterval` function to keep calling a function repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `window.setInterval` for this.
Check http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

```
window.setInterval("first", 5000);
```

Comment: 1. Don't use a string as the first parameter of `setInterval` or `setTimeout` 2. Don't use w3schools as a reference (http://w3fools.com). Instead use the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

Use setinterval function

[w3schools setinterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Put your method into:

```
window.setInterval(yourfunction(){},time_in_millis);
```

[Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript Timing Events http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp 
to call js function after certain interval of time.

You can do like this:

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function first(){
    /*
        write your AJAX code
    */
    window.setInterval(first, 10000);

    first()  // function recursion logic call  
}
```

This logic will run every interval to call AJAX send operation

Comment: Infinite recursion plus every 10 sconds another infinite recursion. I don't think this will perform well